# Nextjs / Next Auth / Discord

Tags: next.js, discord, next-auth

I'm trying to implement discord oauth2 using the `DiscordProvider` from `next-auth/discord`.

I created a discord oauth app, and I received the `client_id` and client `_secret`.

When I click on "Login with discord", I get this error message:

```
{"client_id": ["Value \"<my-client-id\" is not snowflake."]}
```

What does this error mean?
How can I fix the auth?

---